# Program not doing what is meant to in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int const size = 4;
int row[4];
int column[4];
int row_1[3];
int column_1[3];
int max_row = 16;
int max_column = 16;
int second_year_acts = 0;
int first_year_acts = 0;
int current_row = 9;
int current_column = 9;
char current_char;
int ects = 0;
int movements = 0;
int flag = 0;
int flag_1 = 0;
int flag_2 = 0;
int final_flag = 0;

int is_duplicate(int row[], int column[], int index) {
    int l = 0;
    for ( ;l < index; ++l) {
        if ((row[index] == row[l]) && (column[index] == column[l])) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int isin_table_1(int i, int j, int flag) {
    if (flag == 0) {
        int g = 0;
        for (; g < size; ++g) {
            if (i == column[g] && j == row[g]) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    } else if (flag == 1) {
        int g = 0;
        for (; g < size; ++g) {
            if (i == column[g] && j == row[g]) {
                return g;
            }
        }
    }
}


int isin_table_2(int i, int j, int flag) {
    if(flag==0){
        int g = 0;
        for (; g < 3; ++g) {
            if (i == column_1[g] && j == row_1[g]) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else if(flag==1){
        int g = 0;
        for (; g <3 ; ++g) {
            if (i == column_1[g] && j == row_1[g]) {
                return g;
            }
        }

    }
}




void initialize_game() {
    int i = 0;
    int lower_bound_1 = 8;
    int upper_bound_1 = 10;
    int lower_bound_2 = 6;
    int upper_bound_2 = 12;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int j = 0;
    for (; j < size; ++j) {     /* for ones */
        do {
            row[j] = rand() % (upper_bound_1 - lower_bound_1 + 1) + lower_bound_1;
            column[j] = rand() % (upper_bound_1 - lower_bound_1 + 1) + lower_bound_1;
        } while ((row[j] == 9 && column[j] == 9) || is_duplicate(row, column, j));
    }
    int z = 0;
    for (; z < 3; ++z) {    /* for twos*/
        do {
            row_1[z] = rand() % (upper_bound_2 - lower_bound_2 + 1) + lower_bound_2;
            column_1[z] = rand() % (upper_bound_2 - lower_bound_2 + 1) + lower_bound_2;
        } while (is_duplicate(row_1, column_1, z) || !(
                ((row_1[z] == 6 || row_1[z] == 12) && (column_1[z] >= 6 && column_1[z] <= 12)) ||
                ((column_1[z] == 6 || column_1[z] == 12) && (row_1[z] >= 6 && row_1[z] <= 12)) ||
                (row_1[z] == column_1[z] && (row_1[z] == 6 || row_1[z] == 12))
        ));
    }
    for (; i <size ; ++i) {
        printf(" For ones %d %d\n",row[i],column[i]);
    }
    i=0;
    for (; i <3 ; ++i) {
        printf(" For twos%d %d\n",row_1[i],column_1[i]);
    }
}
void print_board(int current_row, int current_column) {
    printf("Use W(up), A(left), S(down), D(right) to move.\n");
    int i = 1;
    for (; i <= max_row; ++i) {
        int j = 1;
        for (; j <= max_column; ++j) {
            flag_2=0;
            if (isin_table_2(i, j,flag_2)) {
                if (i == current_row && j == current_column) {
                    flag_2 = 1;
                    printf("P ");
                    second_year_acts += 8;
                    column_1[isin_table_2(i, j, flag_2)] = -1;
                    row_1[isin_table_2(i, j, flag_2)] = -1;
                    flag_2 = 0;
                }
                else if(i!=current_row || j!=current_column){
                    printf("2 ");
                }
            } else if (isin_table_1(i, j, flag)) {
                flag=0;
                if (i == current_row && j == current_column) {
                    flag = 1;
                    printf("P ");
                    first_year_acts += 8;
                    column[isin_table_1(i, j, flag)] = 17;
                    row[isin_table_1(i, j, flag)] = 17;
                    flag = 0;
                } else if(i!=current_row || j!=current_column) {
                    printf("1 ");
                }
            }
            else if (i == current_row && j == current_column) {
                printf("P ");
            } else if ((i >= 5 && i <= 13) && (j >= 5 && j <= 13)) {
                if (i == 5 || i == 13 || j == 5 || j == 13 || (i >= 7 && i <= 11 && (j == 7 || j == 11)) ||
                    ((i == 7 || i == 11) && j >= 7 && j <= 11)) {
                    printf("# ");
                } else {
                    printf(". ");
                }
            } else if (i == 16 && j == 16) {
                if(current_row==16 && current_column==16){
                    printf(" P");
                    final_flag=1;
                }
                else{
                    printf("X");
                }
            }
            else {
                printf(". ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nFirst year ACTS %d\n", first_year_acts);
    printf("Second year ACTS %d\n", second_year_acts);
    printf("%d Total ACTS\n",first_year_acts+second_year_acts);
}


void move_player(char direction) {
        int new_row = current_row;
        int new_column = current_column;

        switch (direction) {
            case 'w':
            case 'W':
                new_row--;
                break;
            case 's':
            case 'S':
                new_row++;
                break;
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                new_column--;
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                new_column++;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid input.\n");
        }

        movements++;
        if (first_year_acts < 32 && flag_1==0) {
            if (((new_column >= 7 && new_column <= 11) && (new_row == 7 || new_row == 11)) ||
                (((new_column == 7 || new_column == 11)) && (new_row >= 7 && new_row <= 11))) {
                if (direction == 'a' || direction == 'A') {
                    new_column++;
                } else if (direction == 'd' || direction == 'D') {
                    new_column--;
                } else if (direction == 'S' || direction == 's') {
                    new_row--;
                } else if (direction == 'W' || direction == 'w') {
                    new_row++;
                }
                printf("You can not pass the first year  if you your acts is below 32\n");
            }
        }
        else if (first_year_acts==32){
            flag_1=1;
        }
        if (second_year_acts < 24 &&flag_1==1) {
            if (((new_column >= 5 && new_column <= 13) && (new_row == 5 || new_row == 13)) ||
                (((new_column == 5 || new_column == 13)) && (new_row >= 5 && new_row <= 13))) {
                if (direction == 'a' || direction == 'A') {
                    new_column++;
                } else if (direction == 'd' || direction == 'D') {
                    new_column--;
                } else if (direction == 'S' || direction == 's') {
                    new_row--;
                } else if (direction == 'W' || direction == 'w') {
                    new_row++;
                }
                printf("You can not pass the second year  if you your acts is below 32\n");
            }
        }
    if(new_row < 1 || new_column < 1 || new_row > max_row || new_column > max_column){

        new_row = current_row;
        new_column = current_column;
        printf("YOU'VE GONE OUT OF BOUNDS!!!\n");
    }

    current_row = new_row;
    current_column = new_column;
    print_board(current_row, current_column);

}

int main() {
    initialize_game();
    print_board(current_row, current_column);
    while (current_row != 16 || current_column != 16) {
        printf("Enter your move (W/A/S/D): ");
        scanf(" %c", &current_char);
        move_player(current_char);
    }
    printf("Congrats you've graduated!!!");

    return 0;
}
```

This is my program which works fine when I use the gcc version that I've already have which is Apple clang version 15.0.0. However, when I try to compile this program with using gcc version 11.4 when the letter 'P' is placed instead of a number it automatically deletes a random number. I've tried `tocolumn_1[isin_table_2(i, j, flag_2)] = -1;`

`row_1[isin_table_2(i, j, flag_2)] = -1;` changes this values by assign them to another number which is not between 0 and 16 which is the table's length (16x16) surprisingly this works like %10 sometimes it compiles likes as it should but other times it just does what is previously does.

Comment: Simplify, don't use global variables, and learn how to debug your programs.

Comment: looks like `isin_table_1` and `isin_table_2` aren't always returning values

Comment: I also recommend you basically scrap all your code and start over with an empty `main` function. Build with extra warnings enabled, and treated as errors. When it builds cleanly, test the program. When it works you add a ***very small*** piece of code, perhaps just one or two lines. Build and test as before. And so on. This will make it ***much*** easier to isolate problems and errors, to create a [mre], and to debug only the parts needed.

Comment: Add the flags `-Wall -Werror` to your compiler invocation.

Comment: Your functions don't return a value if they don't find a match. You need a unique return value that indicates failure.

Comment: I also recommend you learn about [the KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [separation of concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Some of your functions are way too complex and seem to do too much. More and smaller and simpler functions make the code much easier to understand and debug. Also there's a lack of comment explaining what the code is doing and why it does it that specific way, which really helps with understanding and maintaining the code.

Comment: BTW, the loops in the `isin_table_X` functions are identical except for the value they return. Instead of repeating the whole loop, just use a single loop with `return flag ? 1 : g;`

Comment: _"warning: control reaches end of non-void function"_ appears. Crank up the warning level on your compiler and fix all warnings.

Comment: @Barmar yes that's seems to be the issue. However when I change the version of the compiler to my current version program works just fine.

Comment: Not returning a value causes undefined behavior, so different compilers are likely to produce different results.